# Copy multiple cells linked to a keyword from one column into one cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy cell values linked to keywords from multiple worksheets into one cell in an overview worksheet. The code works if the keyword only appears once on a worksheet, but if the keyword appears multiple times it only copy and pastes the cell value in the row where the keyword appears first.

Code created by my predecessor.

```vb
Public Sub refresh_previous_occupation()
Dim WSUE As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim str As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim finalrow_ue As Integer
Dim wsarr(6) As Variant

'Array with worksheets that shouldn't be searched
wsarr(0) = Tabelle1.Name
wsarr(1) = Tabelle2.Name
wsarr(2) = Tabelle3.Name
wsarr(3) = Tabelle15.Name
wsarr(4) = Tabelle17.Name
wsarr(5) = Tabelle16.Name
wsarr(6) = Tabelle19.Name

Set WSUE = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Übersicht")
finalrow_ue = WSUE.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Search for all keywords in the overview worksheet
For i = 7 To finalrow_ue
    str = "" 'reset string variable
    For n = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count 'look through all worksheets
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(n)
        If isinarray(ws.Name, wsarr) = False And ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then 'check if worksheet is in the array with worksheets that shouldn't be searched an if the worksheet is visible
            Set rng = ws.Range("A7:A100").Find(what:=WSUE.Cells(i, 1), LookIn:=xlValues) 'Search for the current keyword on worksheet
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                If str = "" Then 'check if string variable is filled already
                    If Not rng.Offset(0, 1) = "" Then
                        str = rng.Offset(0, 1).value & " (" & ws.Name & ")" 'add cell value to string variable
                    End If
                Else
                    If Not rng.Offset(0, 1) = "" Then
                        str = str & "; " & vbCrLf & rng.Offset(0, 1).value & " (" & ws.Name & ")" 'add cell value to string variable
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next n
    
    WSUE.Cells(i, 2) = str 'Add string variable value to overview

Next i

End Sub
```

Is it possible to add a loop to search through the worksheets again to find every instance of the keyword or am I going to have to find a new way to  solve my problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO. A data example would be helpful. Also, check method [Range.FindNext method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your search range is relatively small, so a simple loop over the cells should be fine - no real need for `Find()`:

```vb
Public Sub refresh_previous_occupation()
    Dim WSUE As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim str As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim finalrow As Integer
    Dim finalrow_ue As Integer
    Dim wsarr As Variant, f, s, c As Range
    
    'Array with worksheets that shouldn't be searched
    wsarr = Array(Tabelle1.Name, Tabelle2.Name, Tabelle15.Name, _
                  Tabelle16.Name, Tabelle19.Name)

    Set WSUE = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Übersicht")
    finalrow_ue = WSUE.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Search for all keywords in the overview worksheet
    For i = 7 To finalrow_ue
        f = WSUE.Cells(i, 1)   'looking for this
        str = ""               'reset string variable
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            'check sheet not in list to ignore
            If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, wsarr, 0)) Then
                'search range is small, so a simple loop is fine here...
                For Each c In ws.Range("A7:A100").Cells
                    If c.Value = f Then
                        s = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
                        If Len(s) > 0 Then
                            If Len(str) > 0 Then str = str & vbLf 'add new line if needed
                            str = str & s & " (" & ws.Name & "," & c.Address(0, 0) & ")"
                        End If
                    End If
                Next c
            End If
        Next ws
        WSUE.Cells(i, 2) = str 'Add string variable value to overview
    Next i
End Sub
```